# Slicing file via Javascript for upload to Dropbox API gets received into the server as incomplete/corrupt

Tags: javascript, php, api, file, dropbox

I was wondering if anyone could take a peek at this javascript. It takes a file and slices it with a for loop and sends the sliced bits to the backend which gets sent to the Dropbox API.  when they get put in the dropbox, they're missing quite a few megabytes, and dont open how they should.  For example, I sent an avi file and the video is about a quarter of the length its supposed to be.  If anyone has nay ideas please let me know.

```
    for(let start = 0; start < file.size; start += chunkSize){
        const slice = file.slice(start,start + chunkSize + 1)
        const fd = new FormData()
        fd.append('data', slice)
        //count tells the server which api endpoint to hit (start sessions/append to session)
        fd.append('count', start)
        if(start != 0){
        fd.append('session_id',sessionID)
        fd.append('offset', uploadedSoFar)
        }
        uploadedSoFar += slice.size;

        await fetch('/wp-content/plugins/Basic/chunks.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: fd
        })  .then(response => response.text() )
            .then((result) =>{
                
                if(start == 0){
                const json = JSON.parse(result); 
                sessionID = json['session_id']
                console.log(sessionID)
                }
                console.log(result)
                //finishChunk()
            });
    }
    const fd2 = new FormData();
    fd2.append('session_id', sessionID)
    const filepath = window.filePath;
    const filename = file.name;
    fd2.append('path', `${filepath}${filename}`)
    fd2.append('filesize', uploadedSoFar)
    fetch('/wp-content/plugins/Basic/finishchunk.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: fd2
        })  .then(response => response.text() )
            .then(result=>{
                console.log(result)
            });
 
    }
```